# Dúvida sobre Herança

Tags: java, herança, polimorfismo

Tenho o seguinte caso:

**Avo.java:**

```
public class Avo {
    public String quemEuSou(){
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

**Mae.java:**

```
public class Mae extends Avo{
    @Override
    public String quemEuSou() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

**Filho.java:**

```
public class Filho  extends Mae{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Filho filho = new Filho();
        Mae mae = (Mae)filho;
        Avo avo = (Avo) mae;
        System.out.println(filho.quemEuSou());
        System.out.println(mae.quemEuSou());
        System.out.println(avo.quemEuSou());

    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

> Filho
>   Filho
>   Filho

Porque quando realizamos o `cast` a classe continua sendo a que foi instanciada?

Se ela ainda é a instanciada, como é atribuída as propriedades das outras classes?

Exemplo:

```
Filho filho2 = new Filho();
    Mae mae2 = (Mae)filho2;
mae2.algumMetodoDaClasseMae();
```

Se a classe da mae2 é `Filho`, onde está o método `algumMetodoDaClasseMae()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Porque quando realizamos o cast a classe continua sendo a que foi instanciada?

Primeiro é importante entender a diferença de objeto e variável de referência. Ao fazer:

```
Filho filho = new Filho();
```

Você criou uma variável de referência do tipo `Filho`, essa variável se chama `filho`. Isso foi o que foi definido antes do operador de atribuição `=`.

Ao lado direito do `=` você cria um objeto do tipo `Filho` com o uso do operador `new`, e com o operador `=` você o atribui a variável `filho`.

Quebrando essa linha em partes ficaria assim:

```
Filho filho; //cria a variável, que não referencia ninguém
filho = new Filho(); //cria o objeto e o atribui a variável filho
```

Ou seja, só existe um objeto no seu código todo, e ele é do tipo `Filho`, só que você o atribui a diferentes tipos de variáveis de referência, mas isso não muda o tipo do objeto.

> Se ela ainda é a instanciada, como é atribuída as propriedades das outras classes?

As subclasses herdam os métodos e atributos que lhe são visíveis da superclasse, se for desejável pode-se sobrescrevê-los, mas não é obrigatório, a não ser que sejam abstratos na superclasse.

> Se a classe da mae2 é Filho [...]

Correção: O **objeto** é do tipo `Filho`, já a variável de referência é do tipo `Mae`.

> [...] onde está o método algumMetodoDaClasseMae()?

Como explicado dois itens antes, as subclasses herdam os atributos e métodos da superclasse. Desde que não sejam privados.

Comment: Excelente explicação @Math♦

Answer (score 13):

## Sobre a natureza do exemplo

`Avô`, `Pai`/`Mãe` e `Filho` são péssimos exemplos de herança e talvez seja isso que tenha causado confusão.

Se uma classe `Gato` herda da classe `Animal`, dizemos que um `Gato` é um `Animal` e isso faz sentido.

Se eu tiver um `Animal` dentro de uma caixa, faz todo sentido alguém perguntar *que tipo de `Animal` está ali*. Veja, a referência é `Animal`, mas o objeto não muda, ele continua sendo o mesmo de antes, seja `Gato`, `Cachorro` ou `Papagaio`.

Por outro lado, um `Filho` é um `Pai` ou `Avô`? Se eu tiver um `Avô`, faz sentido eu perguntar se ele também é um `Filho` ou um `Pai`?

Herança é um relacionamento do tipo `é-um` e não do tipo `originou-de`. Uma subclasse é aquela que tem tudo que a superclasse tem e **mais alguma coisa**.

## Cast não afeta o objeto

Quando você faz cast em Java, isso não muda em nada o valor do objeto.

Pense da seguinte forma, quando você atribui `filho` para `mae` assim:

```
Mae mae = (Mae) filho;
```

Você simplesmente pegou uma roupinha da mamãe e colocou no filho. Agora todos olham para o filho e pensam que ela é a mãe, mas a pessoa que está lá dentro é a mesma, apenas o visual ficou diferente.

Assim como o filho não vai aprender a cozinhar uma lasanha só por vestir a roupa da mãe, um objeto não ganhar ou perder comportamentos ao ser referenciado por outro tipo de variável. Tudo o que muda é a forma como os outros vêem aquele objeto.

Enfim, o resultado do seu programa imprime `Filho` três vezes, sendo que na segunda vez ele está com a roupa da mãe e na terceira com a roupa do avô.

Comment: +1 pela lasanha, kkkkkk

Comment: A expressão "herança" é um tanto confusa. Prefiro o termo "extensão", no sentido de que `A` é uma extensão do conceito de `B` (afinal, classes representam conceitos), mas já está um pouco tarde para mudar o nome das coisas. :)

Comment: @Pablo Faz sentido. Acho que o termo herança foi criado para fazer uma analogia com um conceito conhecido e o resultado não é muito bom. E acredito que você possa sim substituir em geral por "extensão sem muito prejuízo, afinal, até o Java usa a palavra-chave "extends". Me parece que o criador da linguagem sabia bem disso que estamos tratando aqui.

Answer (score 8):

Esse é o comportamento desejável para termos o polimorfismo.

Ao fazer o cast, a classe não é convertida, mas ela pode ser entendida como uma classe da qual herdou. Isso é vantajoso para que você consiga, por exemplo, fazer uma fábrica de objetos.

Então você pode fazer Carro, Computador, Smartphone e ter uma lista de objetos.
Sua fábrica vai poder chamar métodos que todos os objetos conhecem e cada um vai tratar do seu jeito especializado.