# Polimorfismo ou herança?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, herança, polimorfismo

Estou aprendendo sobre polimorfismo e fiquei na duvida se o que estou fazendo é de fato polimorfismo ou somente herança?

Se for polimorfismo o que tem no meu código que eu posso identificar com clareza que é polimorfismo?

Se não for, o que poderia ser feito para ser polimorfismo?

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public abstract int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Nome { get; set; }

    public abstract void Andar();
}

public class Comprador : Pessoa
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }  
    public override string Nome { get; set; }      

    public override void Andar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Comprar()
    {

    }
}

public class Vendedor : Pessoa
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public override string Nome { get; set; }

    public override void Andar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Vender()
    {

    }
}

public class Sistema
{
    public void MeuMetodoTeste()
    {
        Comprador pessoaComprador = new Comprador();
        pessoaComprador.Comprar();

        Vendedor pessoaVendedor = new Vendedor();
        pessoaVendedor.vender();
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionada a [Herança e Polimorfismo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80948/heran%c3%a7a-e-polimorfismo)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173152.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Está fazendo ambos. Quando coloca `Comprador : Pessoa` ou `Vendedor : Pessoa` está fazendo herança, ou seja, o primeiro nome está definindo uma classe que será composta inicialmente pela classe referenciada no segundo nome. Está `Comprador` e `Vendedor` será subclasses e subtipos de `Pessoa`.

Essas duas classes concretas podem ser usadas no lugar onde se espera a classe abstrata `Pessoas`, portanto nesse caso ocorrerá o polimorfismo. No caso ele ocorrerá de fato em outro lugar do código. Ele não ocorreu no seu exemplo porque não precisou haver uma substituição. Essas classes foram usadas para criar objetos do próprio tipo declarado e não foram usados em outro lugar.

Dá para perceber que o polimorfismo ocorrerá de forma mais clara nos métodos declarados em `Pessoa`. Como todos eles são abstratos, obrigatoriamente eles precisarão ser implementados nas classes descendentes. E para que essas implementações sejam usadas um mecanismo polimórfico precisa ser adotado.

Aqui começa ocorrer o polimorfismo de forma concreta:

```
public class Sistema {
    public void MeuMetodoTeste() {
        var pessoaComprador = new Comprador();
        pessoaComprador.Comprar();
        UmOutroMetodo(pessoaComprador);
        var pessoaVendedor = new Vendedor();
        pessoaVendedor.vender();
        UmOutroMetodo(pessoaVendedor);
    }
    //note que se passar um objeto do tipo Pessoa nem funcionaria de fato, deve ser conreto
    public void UmOutroMetodo(Pessoa pessoa) {
        Console.WriteLine(pessoa.Nome); //vai pegar o que foi usado na classe concreta
        pessoa.Andar(); //vai lançar a exceção
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vThyHZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CH2YGz). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Polimorphism.cs).

Note que o polimorfismo se dá concretamente quando há um método virtual (os métodos abstratos são virtuais por definição). Um método virtual pode ser sobrescrito (os abstratos devem, afinal eles não possuem implementação). Note que só pode haver substituição se o método tiver exatamente a mesma assinatura. A substituição se dá através da palavra-chave `override`.

Isso pode ser melhor explicado em um sentido mais geral em outras perguntas (já respondi isso de formas diferentes em diversos locais - tem exemplos melhores para mostrar o polimorfismo nestas perguntas):

- [Quando usar polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101)
- [Quais as diferenças entre os conceitos de polimorfismo e sobrescrita em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101)
- [Como funciona o "new" e o "virtual" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101)
- [Isso é polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142596/101)
- [Dúvida sobre Herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113797/101)
- [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)
- [Classes que implementam interfaces são consideradas subclasses?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101) (note que esse exemplo `Pessoa` podia ser uma interface)
- [Referência da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [A pergunta mais votada no SO sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1031273/221800)

Comment: Fiquei confuso você disse que para se dá concretamente que é polimorfismo quando o método (deve ter) tem a mesma assinatura, na resposta do @Cigano Morrison Mendez ele diz que pode ter assinaturas diferentes, fiquei em cima do muro :/

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Note que o Gabriel Katakura comenta lá que aquilo não é polimorfismo (pelo menos não o clássico que você está fazendo na sua pergunta). Aquilo é sobrecarga. Eu te dei várias referências (a maioria é minha, mas tem de outras pessoas) todas muito bem votadas que confirmam o que eu disse e possuem *links* para outras referências que pode seguir e ver que escrevi o correto. E tenho ouro em OOP http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/187/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos :P :D Coloquei mais referências na minha resposta. Se não te convenci me diga, tento achar outra forma.

Comment: Entendi, desculpe por fazer esse questionamento, apenas fiquei em cima do muro por vocês serem tão bem conceituados aqui no fórum e eu ter tão pouco conhecimento sobre o assunto. Bom então vou considerar fora de contexto a resposta do @Cigano Morrison Mendez para não confundir mais minha cabeça. :) vou dar uma passada completa nas referencias que você postou. Obrigado.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz não tem porque pedir desculpas, está no seu papel. Se ainda tiver outras dúvidas abra novas perguntas específicas. As perguntas são tão importantes para o sucesso do site quanto as respostas. A sua vai ajudar muita gente que ainda não entende do assunto. Se quiser saber sobrecarga de métodos, tem perguntas sobre o assunto, se nada te atender, pergunte. Cuidado para não confundir sobrecarga de métodos com operadores. São coisa diferentes e já vi algumas pessoas respondendo coisa errada. Sobrecarga não é um conceito de OOP (ainda que polimorfismo também não seja exclusivamente).