# Por que estou 'chamando' o método da subclasse?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

```
public class A { 
  public String imprimir() {
  return "A";
       }
}

 public class B extends A { 
   public String imprimir() {
  return "B";
        }
 }

public class C extends B { 
   public String imprimir() {
  return "C";
        }
 }



public class Executa{


  public static void main (String[] args){

   A v1 = new A();
    System.out.println(v1.imprimir());


   A v2 = new B();
    System.out.println(v2.imprimir());

   A v3 = new C();
    System.out.println(v3.imprimir());


    System.out.println(((A)v3).imprimir());
    System.out.println(((B)v3).imprimir());


  }

}
```

Aparentemente um código bem didático e de fácil compreensão, porém me confundiu bastante.

Por que nas linhas

```
System.out.println(((A)v3).imprimir());
System.out.println(((B)v3).imprimir());
```

está 'chamando' o método da subclasse? Não deveria chamar, respectivamente, os métodos das classe A e classe B?

Acredito que estou errando em algum conceito de orientação a objetos, mas em qual conceito?

Comment: O fato de fazer cast não faz com que o objeto tipo `C` se torne `A` nem `B`. Ele continua sendo `C`. Lembre-se que cast não é conversão, você não está convertendo tipos, está apenas usando [poliformismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154428/28595), uma vez que `C` também é um tipo de `A` e também `B`.

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno já conseguiu dar uma esclarecida nas idéias aqui! mas para chamar o método da superclasse A, deveria usar super ? Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) é justamente o oposto do que acha que é. Ele indica que o objeto concreto é que determina o que será executado e não o tipo que está esperando.

Sem o polimorfismo aconteceria o que está esperando, então ele chamaria sempre o tipo determinado para uso naquela operação. No seu exemplo sem o polimorfismo ele iria imprimir o método do tipo, então imprimiria "A" e "B" pois o tipo é que manda.

Se você quer imprimir "A" você tem que criar um objeto do tipo `A`. Se o objeto é `C` muitas coisas nele podem ser diferentes do que deveria ser em `A`, eles não são substituíveis nas duas direções. `C` substitui `A` de forma perfeita porque ele tem tudo de `A` e algo mais. `A` não pode substituir `C` porque ele não tem tudo o que `C` tem.

Se tentar no seu código ele poderia até dar certo porque você está vendo que tem tudo, mas para o compilador é complicado saber disso, ele tem que ir pelo caminho mais seguro e se tem potencial de erro ele não deixa compilar, até porque mesmo que hoje esteja ok, um dia pode mudar e aí quebrar todos os contratos.

Quanto a usar o `super` ela é uma palavra-chave contextual e só funciona dentro da classe herdada, não é possível usar no consumo do objeto, é algo para indicar ao compilador o que pegar quando há ambiguidade ou falta de informação do que está disponível, no objeto não existe isto. E nem faria sentido pelo que mostrei acima.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Como já foi comentado, o casting não muda o objeto - ele passa um "recado" para o compilador de que naquele contexto ele pode considerar aquele objeto como sendo daquela classe.

Mas no tempo de execução, o método chamado é o do próprio objeto - no caso acima, o `C.imprimir`. Se o método chamado não existisse na superclasse (isso é, se  `imprimir` só estivesse definido para as classes B e C, o compiladordaria um erro - já que não teria como gerar código para chamar o método `imprimir` de um objeto da classe A.

Agora, quanto a sua preocupação de "não estar entendendo algum conceito de orientação a objetos": fique tranquilo - você entendeu O.O. -  o "casting" que é algo que a linguagem Java pega por empréstimo do C que não é algo muito "orientado a objetos", e, sim, mais como um mecanismo para permitir que o compilador se ache em alguns casos.

Se fosse em Python por exemplo, outra linguagem orientada a objetos - em Python não existe o "casting" - mas você sempre pode chamar métodos na própria classe passando a instância explicitamente - nesse caso,  que você está tentando fazer funcionaria:

```
class A:
    def i(self):
        return "A"
class B(A):
    def i(self):
        return "B"
b = B()
print(b.i())
print(A.i(b))
```

Imprime a saída B e A - isso é, se o método é chamado na instância, como é obrigatório na sintaxe do Java, o parâmetro `self`, equivalente ao `this`, é preenchido pela própria linguagem - mas você tem a opção de chamar o método a partir da classe - `A.i()` - e nesse caso tem que passar o que seria o `self` explicitamente - então é possível chamar métodos das superclasses em instâncias de subclasses.

O `super` do Java não pode te dar uma referência direto aos métodos da superclasse se usado de fora das subclasses. Ele existe dentro de um método, sem argumentos, então assume aponta diretamente para o objeto na super-classe, mas se você tentasse usar `super` de dentro de `Executa`, ele procuraria o método `imprimir` em alguma super-classe de `Executa`, e não de `C`. (Novamente, o `super()` de Python permite que se passe explicitamente a classe e a instância da qual se quer acessar os atributos da superclasse. Na continução do exemplo acima, a chamada abaixo imprime `A` )

```
print(super(B, b).i())
```

O ideal seria uma forma de converter seus objetos para a classe desejada, e a única forma limpa de fazer isso é ter um método explícito para conversão, que seja chamado na subclasse e devolva um objeto da classe desejada.

Achei no SOen uma pergunta parecida, onde as respostas, inclusive usando reflection, indicam que realmente não é possível chamar um método de super-classe a partir de uma instância de uma subclasse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411434/how-to-call-a-superclass-method-using-java-reflection

Answer (score -5):

No Java, todos os métodos são virtuais. Uma vez que você sobrescreva um método, a nova implementação é definitiva.