# Instanciando uma classe "x" a partir de outra classe "y" herdada pela classe "x"

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança, instanciar-objeto

Se eu tenho uma classe `Diretor` que herda da classe `Funcionario`, então eu digo que um direto também é um funcionário.

```
Public class Diretor : Funcionario{}
```

---

```
Diretor diretor = new Diretor();
```

Mas me é permitido instanciar

```
Funcionario funcionario = new Diretor();
```

Qual é o real sentido se eu tenho acesso a somente a classe funcionário?

Comment: Se você sabe dirigir um carro, e pega uma picape (que é herdada de carro), você tem a mesma interface, consegue dirigir a picape normalmente, a ideia é essa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso mostrado desse jeito não faz muito sentido, mas é uma forma simples e óbvia de mostrar como funciona o mecanismo.

O que em geral o pessoal não entende é justamente isso, e provavelmente um dos maiores motivos das pessoas aprenderem uma série de coisas de forma errada em programação, especialmente orientado a objeto, já que exemplos e documentação só quer mostrar o mecanismo e não dar uma receita de bolo de como usa, mas a maioria das pessoas entendem que aquilo é exatamente como deve fazer.

Vou dar um exemplo: todo mundo ensina herança mostrando que o cachorro herda de animal, porque é uma forma fácil de entender herança, aí todo mundo modela errado porque não entende o que é o mesmo objeto com uma classificação mais abstrata ou o que é outro objeto completamente diferente que tem alguma relação pontual. Então as pessoas acreditam que um `Diretor` é um `Funcionario`, sendo que existem diretores que não são funcionários e tem funcionários que tem mais de um cargo, ou até trocam de cargo e vira uma bagunça quando tem que mudar essas coisas. `Funcionario` é uma forma de contratação de uma `Pessoa` e `Diretor` é um cargo que uma pessoa tem, não há herança entre essas coisas, há [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) em alguma forma de [composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Veja mais em [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101).

Mas vamos seguir esse exemplo fictício.

Em algum lugar da aplicação você faz algo específico para fazer com um funcionário, não importa em que classe. Então você tem um método que recebe um objeto que seja um `Funcionario` e lá dentro faz tudo o que ele tem que fazer, lembrando que ele só sabe o que é o `Funcionario` e só pode acessar elementos desse tipo. Inclusive porque essa classe é herdada por outras classes então o objeto concreto que esse método está recebendo pode ser também um outro tipo mais específico. Nenhum problema porque se houve herança é garantido que esse objeto tem tudo o que `Funcionario` tem e o método só acessa essas partes do objeto, então ele pode receber um objeto que seja concretamente um `Diretor` que foi criado em algum lugar.

Algo assim:

```
void Print(Funcionario funcionario) { ... }
```

Faz mais sentido na maioria dos cenários. E aí chamará algo como:

```
Print(new Diretor());
```

Percebeu que o objeto é de um tipo mas a variável, no caso parâmetro, que receberá o objeto é declarado de do tipo base `Funcionario`?

Essa é toda a base do que é [herança e polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154421/101).

Quando você faz:

```
Funcionario funcionario = new Diretor();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Polymorphism.cs).

Está dizendo que o [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) é do tipo `Diretor` e a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é do tipo `Funcionario` (um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) assim parece errado, mas não tem problema se é só para demonstrar o mecanismo, só é um problema se achar que sempre deve criar desse jeito).

Existe razão para criar um objeto com o tipo concreto e já dizer que o tipo da variável é o tipo base em vez do tipo do objeto? Tem, se já é certo que depois será usado com o tipo base, no caso `Funcionario`, mas que depois pode usar com o tipo mais específico.

Entenda que em casos assim `Funcionario` provavelmente é uma classe abstrata e não pode ser instanciada (se não for, provavelmente a hierarquia está mais errada ainda por permitir ter um funcionário que não tem cargo mesmo que todos cargos dependam de ser serem funcionários), então se você quer o tipo `Funcionario` para o que for usar ali ainda teria que instanciar através de um objeto `Diretor`.

Se não precisa fazer isso, não faça. E só entenda que só dá para aprender aplicar mecanismo do jeito correto com contextos claros e reais, os artificiais desensinam essa parte. Se tivesse um contexto na pergunta dava para responder com mais propriedade, mas parece que não há contexto mesmo exceto por ser um exemplo artificial.